# What causes my "‘FatalError’ in namespace ‘Foam’ does not name a type" error?

Tags: c++

I have a strange error that I did not manage to solve for some time now. I want to extend one C++ software package by using it together with Intel OpenVINO's inference engine. Therefore I have to dynamically link some libraries and include some headers into the existing code. Before, it compiles without any errors. Then I include the first header file (#include "inference_engine.hpp") which is found, but I get this error message

```
In file included from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpaceI.H:26:0,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpace.H:230,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/Vector.H:44,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/vector.H:39,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/fieldTypes.H:35,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/primitiveFieldsFwd.H:36,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:44,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:316:13: error: ‘FatalError’ in namespace ‘Foam’ does not name a type
     ::Foam::FatalError((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
             ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:358:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘FatalErrorIn’
     FatalErrorIn(functionName)                                                 \
     ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘notImplemented’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                        ^
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_common.h:210:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘NotImplemented’
 class NotImplemented : public std::logic_error
       ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:225:27: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘__PRETTY_FUNCTION__’
     #define FUNCTION_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                           ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:316:25: note: in definition of macro ‘FatalErrorIn’
     ::Foam::FatalError((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
                         ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘notImplemented’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                        ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘FUNCTION_NAME’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                                       ^
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_common.h:210:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘NotImplemented’
 class NotImplemented : public std::logic_error
       ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:225:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__PRETTY_FUNCTION__’
     #define FUNCTION_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                           ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:316:25: note: in definition of macro ‘FatalErrorIn’
     ::Foam::FatalError((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
                         ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘notImplemented’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                        ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘FUNCTION_NAME’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                                       ^
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_common.h:210:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘NotImplemented’
 class NotImplemented : public std::logic_error
       ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/messageStream.H:225:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__PRETTY_FUNCTION__’
     #define FUNCTION_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                           ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:316:25: note: in definition of macro ‘FatalErrorIn’
     ::Foam::FatalError((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
                         ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘notImplemented’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                        ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘FUNCTION_NAME’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                                       ^
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_common.h:210:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘NotImplemented’
 class NotImplemented : public std::logic_error
       ^
In file included from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_blob.h:20:0,
                 from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp:16,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:68,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_common.h:210:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘:’ token
 class NotImplemented : public std::logic_error
                      ^
In file included from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp:16:0,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:68,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_blob.h: In static member function ‘static size_t InferenceEngine::Blob::product(const SizeVector&)’:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_blob.h:245:75: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
         return std::accumulate(std::begin(dims), std::end(dims), (size_t) 1, std::multiplies<size_t>());
                                                                           ^
In file included from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp:18:0,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:68,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_error.hpp: At global scope:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_error.hpp:16:7: warning: ‘class InferenceEngine::IErrorListener’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
 class IErrorListener {
       ^
In file included from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpaceI.H:26:0,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/VectorSpace.H:230,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/Vector.H:44,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/vector.H:39,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/fieldTypes.H:35,
                 from /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/primitiveFieldsFwd.H:36,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:44,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/details/ie_exception_conversion.hpp: In function ‘void InferenceEngine::details::extract_exception(InferenceEngine::StatusCode, char*)’:
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:359:47: error: ‘FatalError’ was not declared in this scope
         << "Not implemented" << ::Foam::abort(FatalError);
                                               ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘notImplemented’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                        ^
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/details/ie_exception_conversion.hpp:60:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘NotImplemented’
         case NOT_IMPLEMENTED:throw NotImplemented(msg);
                                    ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:359:47: note: suggested alternative:
         << "Not implemented" << ::Foam::abort(FatalError);
                                               ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:367:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘notImplemented’
 #define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
                        ^
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/details/ie_exception_conversion.hpp:60:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘NotImplemented’
         case NOT_IMPLEMENTED:throw NotImplemented(msg);
                                    ^
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:303:16: note:   ‘Foam::FatalError’
 extern error   FatalError;
                ^
In file included from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/cpp/ie_plugin_cpp.hpp:16:0,
                 from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_plugin_dispatcher.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp:21,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:68,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/details/ie_exception_conversion.hpp:60:55: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
         case NOT_IMPLEMENTED:throw NotImplemented(msg);
                                                       ^
In file included from /opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp:21:0,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:68,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_plugin_dispatcher.hpp: At global scope:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/ie_plugin_dispatcher.hpp:20:7: warning: ‘class InferenceEngine::PluginDispatcher’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
 class PluginDispatcher {
       ^
In file included from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:68:0,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp: In function ‘void InferenceEngine::TopResults(unsigned int, InferenceEngine::TBlob<T>&, std::vector<unsigned int>&)’:
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/inference_engine.hpp:45:57: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
     n = static_cast<unsigned>(std::min<size_t>((size_t) n, input.size()));
                                                         ^
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C: In member function ‘virtual void Foam::combustionModels::FPVANNModel::correctTabulatedANNTransport()’:
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:371:17: warning: unused variable ‘celli_count’ [-Wunused-variable]
             int celli_count = 0;
                 ^
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:404:17: warning: unused variable ‘patch_count’ [-Wunused-variable]
             int patch_count = 0;
                 ^
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:301:16: warning: unused variable ‘Zeta’ [-Wunused-variable]
         double Zeta;
                ^
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C: In member function ‘virtual void Foam::combustionModels::FPVANNModel::correctCalculatedANNTransport()’:
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:605:26: warning: unused variable ‘success’ [-Wunused-variable]
                     bool success = inf->doInference(frozenGraphName,inputOperationName,outputOperationName,no_of_inputs,no_of_outputs,input_dimensions,output_dimensions,cellsAndPatches,input_f_zeta_PVNorm,output_real,limit_intra,limit_inter,xlaJit);
                          ^
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:696:17: warning: unused variable ‘celli_count’ [-Wunused-variable]
             int celli_count = 0;
                 ^
tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:721:17: warning: unused variable ‘patch_count’ [-Wunused-variable]
             int patch_count = 0;
                 ^
In file included from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.H:66:0,
                 from tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.C:31:
/home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/LRT10Foam/src/../ThirdParty/ANNInference/TensorflowCAPI/inferenceC.H: At global scope:
/home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/LRT10Foam/src/../ThirdParty/ANNInference/TensorflowCAPI/inferenceC.H:25:19: warning: ‘TF_Buffer* ReadBufferFromFile(const char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static TF_Buffer* ReadBufferFromFile(const char* file)
                   ^
/home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/LRT10Foam/src/../ThirdParty/ANNInference/TensorflowCAPI/inferenceC.H:55:13: warning: ‘void DeallocateTensor(void*, std::size_t, void*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void DeallocateTensor(void* data, std::size_t, void*) // vorher void* arg
             ^
make: *** [Make/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/tabulatedCombustionModel/FPVANNModel/FPVANNModel.o] Error 1
```

I did not change anything apart from including the additional header, and the error messages are totally weird. One colleauge mentioned that there might be some "conflict" between the two programs involved (OpenFOAM and OpenVINO). Can somebody give me a hint what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Edit: Maybe I should point out to these two sections:

```
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:316:13: error: ‘FatalError’ in namespace ‘Foam’ does not name a type
     ::Foam::FatalError((functionName), __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

```
/opt/intel_openvino/openvino/inference_engine/include/details/ie_exception_conversion.hpp: In function ‘void InferenceEngine::details::extract_exception(InferenceEngine::StatusCode, char*)’:
/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/error.H:359:47: error: ‘FatalError’ was not declared in this scope
         << "Not implemented" << ::Foam::abort(FatalError);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is buried around halfway your error dump:

```
#define NotImplemented notImplemented(FUNCTION_NAME)
```

OpenFOAM uses this as a macro to raise an error in unimplemented methods, while OpenVINO happens to define a class with the same name. C++ namespaces are only resolved after macro expansion, so that cannot help you.

Your options, in rough order of preference:

1. Include the OpenVINO headers first, then the OpenFOAM headers. This does mean you have to `#undef NotImplemented` if you also want to throw or catch these exceptions.
2. Include the OpenFOAM headers first, then `#undef NotImplemented`, and include the OpenVINO headers. This means you cannot use the OpenFOAM macro for your own purposes (although you probably do not need to).
3. Remove the macro from the OpenFOAM headers, if no other headers use it.

Comment: There are some more options, but rather expensive. In general it's a good habbit to wrap external library into your own class wrappers (which does poor man's PIMPL, but prevents any problems of that kind). OP's issue is a great lesson, why you should never define a macro, that leaves your header.

Comment: Hi @Botje (and also Radoslaw Cybulski) - I have tried out #1 suggestion, worked fine for now - the error is gone! I will try to include more headers to get all the functionality. Thank you very much, I would have never thought of that as a solution!!

Comment: @tre95 I have [reported this issue](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/OpenFOAM-plus/issues/1371) to OpenFOAM.

Comment: Thanks, however they might already have fixed it, the thing is that I use version 4.1 as our institute massively extended this version and cannot switch to a newer one currently.